# Find missing values on spreadsheet 1 when compared to spreadsheet 2

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I have the following scenario:

I have a list of ID's on a spreadsheet generated from a web app that has to be compared to our internal system. Any missing values from SP1 have to be alerted since the accurate data is the one from our system.

I have never worked using macros in excel (I have no idea if this can be accomplished with a simple formula in Excel). Can somebody give me an idea how to solve this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Put the list of IDs from the web into column A. Get a list of IDs from your system and put them in column B. Then, in column C you can use this formula (row 1 has labels, formula starts in C2):

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A:A,B2),"","ID not found")
```

copy down as far as the last cell in column B.

[image]

Comment: this is weird, all of them are shown as ID not found